# How to make retrofit api request for each item in list with rxjava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm very new to RxJava and although I have seen multiple questions related to the one I am asking, I can't seem to piece them out altogether.

I have a PostPatrol object containing the following data:

```
public class PostPatrol {
   String checkpoint_name;
   String status;
   int user;
   String detail;
   List<String> photos;

   public PostPatrol(int cpId, String checkpoint_name, String detail, List<String> photos, String detail) {
       this.cpId = cpId;
       this.checkpoint_name = checkpoint_name;
       this.detail = detail;
       this.photos = photos;
       this.status = status;
   }

   //getters and setters
}
```

What I'm trying to do now is to save a local list of photos into this PostPatrol record, but before that I have to upload the photos one by one with retrofit, get back a url and save that to a list which I then set as the photos for the PostPatrol record.

Once I save all the needed details for a certain PostPatrol record, I then send that again through retrofit.

Currently, I am doing it this way:

1. I pass the photos to a function to upload the image one by one
2. The function is like this:

   ```
   private void uploadImage(List<String> photos, String folder, long requestId) {
       final int size = photos.size();
       final long reqId = requestId;

       for (String path : photos) {
           File file = new File(path);
           RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
           MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);
           RequestBody folderName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), folder);

           ApiEndpointInterface apiEndpointInterface = RetrofitManager.getApiInterface();

           Call<FileInfo> call4File = apiEndpointInterface.postFile(body, folderName);

           call4File.enqueue(new ApiCallback<FileInfo>() {
               @Override
               protected void do4Failure(Throwable t) {
                   Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
                   snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewPendingRequestLayout, R.string.sb_image_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   snackbar.show();
                   position++;
               }

               @Override
               protected void do4PositiveResponse(Response<FileInfo> response) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Uploaded Image");
                   FileInfo fileDetails = response.body();
                   listUrls.add(fileDetails.getImage());
                   position++;
                   if (position == size) {
                       postRequest(reqId);
                       position = 0;
                   }
               }

               @Override
               protected void do4NegativeResponse(Response<FileInfo> response) {
                   String bodyMsg = "";
                   try {
                       bodyMsg = new String(response.errorBody().bytes());
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   Log.d(TAG, bodyMsg);
                   snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewPendingRequestLayout, R.string.sb_image_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   snackbar.show();
                   position++;
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

In `do4PositiveResponse` I use local variables to keep track whether I have uploaded all the photos before sending them to a function where the list is saved to the PostPatrol record. Sometimes though, I get problems where the photos aren't uploaded at all since it fires too late or too early.

3. This is my code on`postRequest()`

   ```
   private void postRequest(long requestId) {
       if(mapIdPatrol.containsKey(requestId)){
           PostPatrol postPatrol = mapIdPatrol.get(requestId);
           postPatrol.setPhotos(listUrls);
           postPatrolRequest(postPatrol, requestId);
       }
       listUrls = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   ```
4. And finally my code on `postPatrolRequest()`

   ```
   private void postPatrolRequest(final PostPatrol postPatrol, final long requestId){
       ApiEndpointInterface apiEndpointInterface = RetrofitManager.getApiInterface();
       Call<ResponseId> call4Handle = apiEndpointInterface.handleCheckpoint(postPatrol);

       call4Handle.enqueue(new ApiCallback<ResponseId>() {
           @Override
           protected void do4Failure(Throwable t) {
               finishUploading();
               Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
           }
           @Override
           protected void do4PositiveResponse(Response<ResponseId> response) {
               RequestsDataSource.removeRequest(getApplication(),requestId);
               finishUploading();
           }
           @Override
           protected void do4NegativeResponse(Response<ResponseId> response) {
               finishUploading();
               String bodyMsg = "";
               try {
                   bodyMsg = new String(response.errorBody().bytes());
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               Log.d(TAG, bodyMsg);
               snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewPendingRequestLayout, getResources().getText(R.string.sb_negative_response), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
               snackbar.show();
           }
       });

   }
   ```

I know this is very inefficient and so I would like your help so I can try to find a way around it with the use of RxJava. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the operation atomic? i.e. if saving some of the photos via Retrofit fails, do you still have to proceed?

Anyway, roughly the solution will be something like that (pseudocode):

```
Observable<String> urls = Observable.from(listOfPhotoFilePaths)
    .flatMapDelayError(path -> { return retrofit.save(readFile(path))})
    .toList()

Observable<PostPatrol> pp = urls
    .map(list -> { return new PostPatrol(list)})
```